# Why can we extract the first term during integral?

Tags: integration

I was reading a manuscript that is relevant to my thesis (essentially a proof for some tail bound) and encountered a formula that looks like this

$f'(z) = f'(0) + \int_0^z f''(w)dw$

for every $z \in [0, x]$.

Since my math background is pretty shaky, I don't quite understand why we are justified to do the step above. Can someone maybe explain this or point me to some useful resources? Many thanks.

Comment: Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f'(x)$  The formula is simply $g(z)-g(0)=\int_0^zg'(w)dw$, which is the general formula for the definite integral.